# What is "the poem" that the spider refers to in Philip Dick's short story "Expendable"?

Tags: meaning, short-stories, philip-k-dick

In the short story "Expendable" by Philip K. Dick, the protagonist is a man who can communicate with spiders. At one point, after fighting off a home invasion by an army of ants, the protagonist is seated at his desk, armed and despairing, when a spider drops by to talk to him.

> The spider slid down beside him onto the desk top. "Sorry. Hope you aren't frightened, as in the poem."

What does this line mean? Is there some famous poem about a man being frightened by a spider landing beside him, or by facing an invasion of ants? If so, is the spider actually supposed to be familiar with literature?

Comment: Yes, the [HNQ](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/234222/79840) from SFF SE motivated this question [too](https://literature.stackexchange.com/q/14829/5387). :)

Comment: Congratulations on [your](https://literature.stackexchange.com/posts/14853/timeline) HNQ too :-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It could be a reference to the classical nursery rhyme [Little Miss Muffet](https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/46957/little-miss-muffet):

> Little Miss Muffet
> Sat on a tuffet,
> Eating her curds and whey;
> Along came a spider,
> Who sat down beside her,
> And frightened Miss Muffet away.

This was what immediately came to my mind on seeing "spider", "beside", and "frightened" in the same sentence. [It's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little_Miss_Muffet) a fairly well-known children's poem, I think (at least in the UK - not sure about the US where Philip K. Dick grew up).

As for whether the spider's supposed to be familiar with literature ... I suspect we aren't supposed to overthink this one. It's a short story, and spiders are depicted as intelligent sentient beings, part of a great war between species. Making a spider character refer to literature helps to emphasise that effect, if you can suspend your disbelief enough not to wonder why spiders would (or could) read human poetry.

Comment: Yes, it's well-known in the US. At least among old fogies such as myself. I'd assume that the kids know it today, also.

Comment: Well-known among kids today in Canada too (well, the ones I know in Victoria and Vancouver, BC).

Answer (score 15):

Mother Goose, in fact.

> Little Miss Muffet 
> Sat on a tuffet,
> Eating her curds and whey;
> Along came a spider,
> Who sat down beside her,
> And frightened Miss Muffet away.

It has the spider, the fright, and being Mother Goose, the pop-cultural awareness for the reader to recognize.